# How to Read Files Stored in Raspberry Pi Directly to Window Using R

Tags: linux, r, windows, ssh, raspberry-pi

I'm attempting to read files stored in Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) directly to Windows 7 using R.

To be specific, here are what I've done so far. 
1. Install R 3.1.2 on Windows 7
2. Install Raspbian on Raspberry Pi, stored some text data files in Raspberry Pi.
3. Attempt to read text file stored in Raspberry Pi to Windows 7 through R 3.1.2.

I've Google on this topic for some time and RCurl package seems to be the answer. However, I keep getting error says "Authentication failure"

Here is the code i use in R @ Windows 7 and the error message i get:

```
library(RCurl)
table1 <- scp(host="192.168.XXX.XXX",path="~/Desktop/Parallel/test.txt",key="D:\\Temp\\id_dsa_win1",user="pi",keypasswd="")
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : Authentication failure
```

I've generated a public/private key pair using PuttyGen in Windows 7 (without passphrase), added the public key into Raspberry Pi and export the private key in OpenSSH format under Windows 7's "D:\Temp\id_dsa_win1". I confirm i can login to my Raspberry Pi using Putty without password. However, R was not able to login to my Raspberry Pi using the generated private key.

I'm out of idea, am i doing this right? Appreciate if someone can help me on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found a way to do this. I use a little help from plink.exe from putty site. Just need to download it and place it on your window local drive.

Use pipe command from R and send the "cat" command to Raspberry Pi with the help of plink.exe and read the csv content to R data frame directly. Here is the command i used:

```
    data <- read.table(pipe(
    "C:\\~path to plink\\plink.exe -v -ssh -P PORTNUMBER username@IPADDRESS -pw 
    \"password\" \"cat ~/Your Data File.csv\"")
    ,header=TRUE,sep=",",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Working great when reading log files inside your Raspberry Pi from Window. Hope this helps others with similar interest.

PS: Some of my window machine not able to read the csv file using the same command, i suspect due to firewall setting in window or router. No time to check on that yet.

Thanks.